# JVM Implementation of Kotlin Set and MutableSet

Tags: kotlin

What implementation class is used to back the `Set<E>` and `MutableSet<E>` types returned by `setOf()` and `mutableSetOf()`?

Since the [api documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-set/index.html) describes `MutableSet` as `A generic unordered collection of elements`, and since elements don't have to be `Comparable`, I'm guessing it's a `HashSet` but I can't find confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look inside Kotlin sources [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/collections/Sets.kt) and [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/libraries/stdlib/common/src/generated/_Arrays.kt), it seems that both return `LinkedHashSet`. There is an exception, in case `setOf()` is provided an empty list, it returns a singleton object (Kotlin object) which is defined at the top of the first file (link).

Comment: Thanks!!  I didn't realize that the Kotlin source code was so accessible.  I'll try and track down my own answer next time.  :)

Comment: Beware: that's an implementation detail which could change in future versions.  (JetBrains would have documented the types if they were guaranteed not to change.  As you can see, there's one case where they differ; more may well be added in future.)  So I strongly suggest you *don't write any code which relies on them returning `LinkedHashMap`s.*